# Changing the .Text of my MenuStripItems

Tags: c#, menustrip

This code only changes the top menu selectors.

```
private void englishToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        menuStrip1.Items[0].Text = Languages.English.File;
        menuStrip1.Items[1].Text = Languages.English.Options;
        menuStrip1.Items[2].Text = Languages.English.Help;
    }
```

How can I change the subitems's .Text properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the form designer code file, you'll see that the menu items are all stored in their own variable, which you can use to change the text.

The default variable names aren't brilliant, having names like "toolStripMenuItem1". I assume you created the menus using the collections editor; if you select the menu item in there, you can change the variable name under the (Name) property.

Personally, I'd suggest naming something along the lines of "menuFileItem1", "menuFileItem2", and so on, as it'll allow you to see the hierarchy of the menu by glancing at the variable names.